# Is There A Way To Show An Enum's Numerical Value In Visual Studio With Resharper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I always wind up adding comments next to `enum` values so I can see their numerical value quickly in the editor.  Otherwise you have to start at 0 (or your initial value) and count up from there (or worse if you want to use `flags`).  My use case is looking at the `enum` in the editor while working with SSMS.

```
enum PossibleValues
{
  AnOption,         //0
  ADifferentOption, //1
  TheLastOption,    //2
}
```

This seems like a feature Visual Studio might have but I can't find it.  Maybe a plugin is necessary?  Google is failing me here.

Edit:  I've added the Resharper tag and specified it in the title.  Since it's available to me and offers a perfect solution.

Comment: See it where?  Generally hovering over them with a mouse will show a tooltip with the value in?  Note also that in your example there, the values are actually 0, 1, 2.

Comment: It is not really clear what you want. Do you want to print out the numeric value of a variable of type PossibleValues?

Comment: Your numbering is off-by-one.

Comment: By the way, your comments are wrong. The AnOption value is zero, then 1 and last 2

Comment: Clarified what I wanted and fixed my numbering oversight.

Comment: So you just want to be able to see what values an enum has when looking at the enum declaration itself?  Are you aware that you can assign them directly, ie `AnOption = 1, ADifferentOption = 2` etc?

Comment: Why do you need to know the numerical value of the enum in the editor? Enums are there because they turn groups of "magic numbers" into textual, easy to understand mnemonics.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I am aware but Resharper has given me an automation itch lately.  I also have a lot of enums in my lazy defense.

Comment: @RonBeyer OP mentions SSMS, ie SQL - they'll just be numbers there.  Looks like they want to quickly be able to look up the corresponding enum entry.

Comment: If you need to see the underlying value while you're writing code, then you should probably be using an int instead.

Comment: @RonBeyer  I recently edited my post to explain why.

Comment: _"Resharper has given me an automation itch lately"_ -> click on enum name, alt-enter, "specify enum member values".  Can do the entire solution in one go if you want.

Comment: If you need the value to be constant. Assign them yourself. If you don't then why would you care about the number

Comment: @Steve Because if I'm writing a one-off SQL Query in SSMS I would need to know the number as SQL Server isn't aware of the Enum in C#.

Comment: @JamesThorpe  I'll gladly mark the Resharper automation as the answer if you'll post it as one.

Comment: @Licht which means you NEED the numbers to be constant. You do not want someone to stick in another enum value in between and messed up your conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that you're using ReSharper - it has the functionality to quickly add in the values if you haven't already assigned them.  Select the enum name, and bring up the usual menu (alt-enter by default):

[image]

Choose "Specify enum member values", and it will populate them directly in code:

[image]

If you click the small arrow, you can also do it per file, folder, project or the entire solution.

Comment: Made a quick edit to specify Resharper as part of the question so your answer is more perfect.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> if I'm writing a one-off SQL Query in SSMS I would need to know the number as SQL Server isn't aware of the Enum in C#.

This means the enum values NEED to stay constant, you do not want someone to put in another value in between your current ones and blow up your DB entries.

In such case you should do

```
enum PossibleValues
{
  AnOption = 0,
  ADifferentOption = 1,
  TheLastOption = 2
}
```

Comment: I'm the only developer and I've always kept it in mind without thinking about it.  You raise a good point and I'll be specifying values from now on.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign values

```
enum ee { one = 1, two = 2, three = 3 }
```

You can cast the enum to int.  That is what I use for building TSQL in code.

```
ee e = ee.three;
Debug.WriteLine((int)e);
```

In SQL I will typically have a table with enum number and value so I can look it up there and present the actual enum in the query.  You need to manually synch them.

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework so the conversion is done for me.